# Problem with extension method

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, extension-methods

I have declared the following extension method:

```
public static T FindAncestor<T>(DependencyObject obj) where T : DependencyObject
{
    while (obj != null)
    {
        T o = obj as T;
        if (o != null)
        {
            return o;
        }
        obj = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(obj);
    }
    return null;
}

[System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()]
public static T FindAncestor<T>(UIElement obj) where T : UIElement
{
    return FindAncestor<T>((DependencyObject)obj);
}
```

It doesn't seem to work with `TextBlock`:

```
var csiPage = (sender as TextBlock).FindAncestor<NotebookPageView>();
```

`NotebookPageView` inherits from `UserControl`.

Why isn't the extension method available?

Comment: After using [FishBasketGordo's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7191523/problem-with-extension-method/7191536#7191536) you should also remove `[System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()]` - there is no reason for you to have it.

Comment: See:- http://geekswithblogs.net/codingbloke/archive/2010/12/19/visual-tree-enumeration.aspx  Especially the code box titled "Real World Scenarios" and the example "Find the containing `ListBoxItem` for a UIElement"

Comment: @Jonathan: Actually that whole overload is probably unnecessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not an extension method. It's just a static method. To make it an extension method you need to use the `this` keyword on the parameter:

```
public static T FindAncestor<T>(this DependencyObject obj)
```

Also, as @Jonathan reminds below, extension methods need to be in a static class, so make sure that's the case in your code.

For more information see the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) on extension methods.

Comment: Also it needs to be in a static class.